# Posting a message while running Gloss code in Haskell

Tags: haskell, gloss

The Haskell playIO has the below type:

```
 playIO:: Display   
-> Color    background color
-> Int  
-> world    --initial world 
-> (world -> IO Picture)  -- function to change world into a picture    
-> (Event -> world -> IO world) --event handler function
-> (Float -> world -> IO world) -- The function to update the world after the given time 
-> IO ()
```

Once you call `playIO`inside `main`, it runs continuously updating the GUI which is modelled by the `world`. In case something happened inside the code  that handles events(see comments on code) or the function that updates the world and you wanted to output a message (Not necessarily an error), what approach would one use that does not violate the types? Would one have to break out of the function `playIO`to display my message  and if so how would one do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to, say, emit a message based on the event then put that operation inside the event handler.  For example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = playIO black 100 world0 renderWorld handleEvent updateWorld

handleEvent evt w =
    do print event -- Right here, you are emitting a message!
       updateWorldWithEvent evt w
       putStrLn "I have updated the world, now time for breakfast."
```

Just keep in mind the `handleEvent` operation will potentially happen quite frequently so select your output accordingly.